# hover + div:show not working

Tags: html, css, hover, display

so i'm trying to get an image to show when you hover over the design now button using btn:hover + img {display:block} using only css, but it's not working and i can't really figure out why.

```css
.ca-sub a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ca-sub p {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.ca-menu {
    padding:0;
    /*margin:20px auto;*/
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.ca-menu li {
    width: 18.5%;
    height: 215px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    background: white;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.ca-menu li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.ca-menu li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.ca-menu li a img {
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
    height: 70%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.ca-content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
.ca-main {
    font-size: 30px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}
.ca-sub {
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 14px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -35px;
    width: 100%; 
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}
/*.ca-sub {
 display: none;
}*/
.ca-menu li:hover { /* enlarges box */
    z-index:999;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);  
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);  
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);   
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);   
    transform: scale(1.1);  
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main {
    -webkit-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
    -moz-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
    -ms-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-sub { /* brings up box from bottom */
    display: block;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    /*background-color: #ccc;*/
    -webkit-animation: moveUp 500ms ease;
    -moz-animation: moveUp 500ms ease;
    -ms-animation: moveUp 500ms ease;
}
.quotebtn {
    width: 49.5% !important;
    background-color: #0fbac1;
    float: left;
    color: white !important;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-family: geo;
}
.designbtn {
    width: 49.5% !important;
    background-color: #EE3443;
    float: right !important;
    color: white !important;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-family: geo;
}
.not {
    color: gray;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.not:hover {
    color: gray !important;
}
.quotebtn:hover, .designbtn:hover {
    color: black !important;
}
.designhere {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom: -150px !important;
}
.designbtn:hover + .designhere {
    display: block !important;
}




@-webkit-keyframes smallToBig{
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes smallToBig{
    from {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes smallToBig{
    from {
        -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFromBottom {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveFromBottom {
    from {
        -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes moveFromBottom {
    from {
        -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}


/* fixes for chrome */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {

}
/* /fixes for chrome */
```

```html
<ul class="ca-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.brokenarrowwear.com/q/i.aspx?b=Fruit%20of%20the%20Loom&m=3930R">
            <img src="http://www.embroiderywear.com/q/img/FRU3930R.jpg" class="designhere" /><img src="http://www.embroiderywear.com/q/img/FRU3930R.png" />
            <div class="ca-content">
                <div class="ca-sub">
                    <p>Fruit of the Loom <br />Cotton T-Shirt</p>
                    <div>
                        <a href="https://www.brokenarrowwear.com/q/i.aspx?b=Fruit%20of%20the%20Loom&m=3930R" class="quotebtn">Get Quote</a>
                        <a href="https://www.brokenarrowwear.com/designer/designer.aspx?name=Fruit%20of%20the%20Loom&sku=3930R#/artLocations" class="designbtn">Design Now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://www.embroiderywear.com/q/hovertest.html here's a test website i set up if you want an online view

Comment: `.designbtn` is not a sibling of `.designhere`.

Comment: oh. is there a way to get .designhere to appear when .designbtn is hovered on? or is it impossible?

Comment: For your HTML structure, this is not possible with CSS. You'd have to use JavaScript.

Comment: can you tell me what is the image you wanna show on hover? so i can try something in css.

Comment: http://www.embroiderywear.com/q/img/FRU3930R.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS `+` selector works **only** when the elements are direct (adjacent) siblings which share the same parent. Another related selector is the tilde `~` which is less strict and allows for other siblings to be in-between.

In your case, `.designbtn` and `.designmore` are **not** siblings and therefore your CSS rule will not work. The current CSS spec does not allow altering of previous elements or unrelated elements.

At this point you are presented with two options: Change HTML structure or use JavaScript to handle the event.

### Change HTML

You could just place the `.designhere` `img` right under the `.designbtn` link in the HTML structure. The result would look like this (I added some CSS rules for demonstration):

```css
.ca-sub a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ca-sub p {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.ca-menu {
  padding: 0;
  /*margin:20px auto;*/
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.ca-menu li {
  width: 18.5%;
  height: 215px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: white;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.ca-menu li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.ca-menu li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.ca-menu li a img {
  text-align: left;
  width: auto;
  height: 70%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.ca-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.ca-main {
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.ca-sub {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -35px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}


/*.ca-sub {
 display: none;
}*/

.ca-menu li:hover {
  /* enlarges box */
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main {
  -webkit-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
  -moz-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
  -ms-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-sub {
  /* brings up box from bottom */
  display: block;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  /*background-color: #ccc;*/
  -webkit-animation: moveUp 500ms ease;
  -moz-animation: moveUp 500ms ease;
  -ms-animation: moveUp 500ms ease;
}

.quotebtn {
  width: 49.5% !important;
  background-color: #0fbac1;
  float: left;
  color: white !important;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: geo;
}

.designbtn {
  width: 49.5% !important;
  background-color: #EE3443;
  float: right !important;
  color: white !important;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: geo;
}

.not {
  color: gray;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.not:hover {
  color: gray !important;
}

.quotebtn:hover,
.designbtn:hover {
  color: black !important;
}

.designhere {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: -150px !important;  
}

/* demo purpose */

.designhere {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
    top: -95px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.designbtn:hover + .designhere {
  display: block !important;
}

@-webkit-keyframes smallToBig {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes smallToBig {
  from {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes smallToBig {
  from {
    -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFromBottom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes moveFromBottom {
  from {
    -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes moveFromBottom {
  from {
    -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}


/* fixes for chrome */

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {}


/* /fixes for chrome */
```

```html
<ul class="ca-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <!-- old place -->
      <img src="http://www.embroiderywear.com/q/img/FRU3930R.png" />
      <div class="ca-content">
        <div class="ca-sub">
          <p>Fruit of the Loom
            <br />Cotton T-Shirt</p>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="quotebtn">Get Quote</a>
            <a href="#" class="designbtn">Design Now</a>
            <!-- new place -->
            <img src="http://www.embroiderywear.com/q/img/FRU3930R.jpg" class="designhere" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/3em6nz9c/

---

### jQuery

If you want to keep your HTML structure then you would not be able to solve the problem with pure CSS, you would need a JavaScript solution, like the following:

```
$(".designbtn").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).parents().eq(3).find('.designhere').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).parents().eq(3).find('.designhere').hide();
    }
});
```

```js
$(".designbtn").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).parents().eq(3).find('.designhere').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).parents().eq(3).find('.designhere').hide();
    }
});
```

```css
.ca-sub a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ca-sub p {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.ca-menu {
  padding: 0;
  /*margin:20px auto;*/
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.ca-menu li {
  width: 18.5%;
  height: 215px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: white;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.ca-menu li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.ca-menu li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.ca-menu li a img {
  text-align: left;
  width: auto;
  height: 70%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.ca-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.ca-main {
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.ca-sub {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -35px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}


/*.ca-sub {
 display: none;
}*/

.ca-menu li:hover {
  /* enlarges box */
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main {
  -webkit-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
  -moz-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
  -ms-animation: smallToBig 300ms ease;
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-sub {
  /* brings up box from bottom */
  display: block;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  /*background-color: #ccc;*/
  -webkit-animation: moveUp 500ms ease;
  -moz-animation: moveUp 500ms ease;
  -ms-animation: moveUp 500ms ease;
}

.quotebtn {
  width: 49.5% !important;
  background-color: #0fbac1;
  float: left;
  color: white !important;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: geo;
}

.designbtn {
  width: 49.5% !important;
  background-color: #EE3443;
  float: right !important;
  color: white !important;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: geo;
}

.not {
  color: gray;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.not:hover {
  color: gray !important;
}

.quotebtn:hover,
.designbtn:hover {
  color: black !important;
}

.designhere {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: -150px !important;  
}

.designbtn:hover + .designhere {
  display: block !important;
}

@-webkit-keyframes smallToBig {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes smallToBig {
  from {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes smallToBig {
  from {
    -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFromBottom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes moveFromBottom {
  from {
    -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes moveFromBottom {
  from {
    -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}


/* fixes for chrome */

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {}


/* /fixes for chrome */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ca-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://www.embroiderywear.com/q/img/FRU3930R.jpg" class="designhere" />
      <img src="http://www.embroiderywear.com/q/img/FRU3930R.png" />
      <div class="ca-content">
        <div class="ca-sub">
          <p>Fruit of the Loom
            <br />Cotton T-Shirt</p>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="quotebtn">Get Quote</a>
            <a href="#" class="designbtn">Design Now</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/jk6Lqu6q/